# rlocus() - Not enough input arguments in MATLAB 2018a

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

I am following [this tutorial](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_PZ) on root locus methods and when writing:

```
syms s
sys = 1/(3*s^2 + 2*s - 1);
rlocus(sys)
```

I get:

> Error using rlocus
>   Not enough input arguments.

Why is `rlocus` expecting more input arguments when the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) states that one input argument is enough?

---

> rlocus(SYS) computes and plots the root locus of the single-input,
>       single-output LTI model SYS. The root locus plot is used to analyze 
>       the negative feedback loop

Syntax for `rlocus`:

```
rlocus(sys)
rlocus(sys1,sys2,...)
[r,k] = rlocus(sys)
r = rlocus(sys,k)
```

When writing:

```
s = tf('s');
P = 1/(3*s^2 + 2*s - 1);
rlocus(P)
```

I get:

> Error using InputOutputModel/subsref (line 43) The name "s" does not
>   match any channel or group.
>
> Error in s = tf('s');

so I am using `syms s` which is used to define symbolic variables.

Strangely `which rlocus` returns `...Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\control\ctrlobsolete\rlocus.m` which is in the `obsolete` folder.

Comment: >> Num=1;
>> Den=[3 2 -1];
>> G=tf(Num,Den);
>> rlocus(G)

Comment: @Chu, this seems correct as per documentation but gives me the error `Subscript no. 2 is out of range.`. I am unable to determine why this is happening.

Comment: Have you run my progam? I've run that exact program on Matlab 2018 and it works fine. Is control systems toolbox in the obsolete folder? If so, it wont work!

Comment: Try 'help rlocus' instead of 'which rlocus'. I've not seen the latter command before.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they helped me solve the pending issue. `which` is a handy command which is used to locate functions and files. `help rlocus` now gives the expected help on how to use the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sys = tf([1],[3 2 -1]); 
rlocus(sys);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That still gives me an error on MATLAB 2018a: `Subscript no. 2 is out of range.`

Comment: @Rrz0 check your syntax. I was going to post this until I saw spehroPefhany posted it. I have just confirmed it in R2018b and R2018a, R2017b

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. Turns out I was using an obselete version of `rlocus`.